# MigLayout strange aligny top behavior

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I don't have a lot of miglayout experience, so please advise.  I have a layout where the first column is a `JCheckBox` that spans 2 rows.  The second column has 2 JLabels, 1 in each row.

It seemed the default layout is for the checkbox to be vertically aligned in the center of the 2 rows.  I want it to be aligned with the text in the top `JLabel`, so I used `aligny top` on the `JCheckBox`.

```
rightSubPanel.add(stepCheck,"span 1 2, aligny top");
rightSubPanel.add(stepTitle);
rightSubPanel.add(subTitle, "gapleft 40");
```

However the `JCheckbox` is still slightly lower than the text in the adjacent `JLabel`.

See the attached picture:

[image: misaligned checkboxes]

Can anyone explain this or suggest a better way to do this?

**update** Using debug the layout looks like below.  The solution is to add a 5 pixel gap above each of the stepTitles such as:

```
rightSubPanel.add(stepTitle,"gaptop 5");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `debug` tag in the constructor of MigLayout. This will show borders around each element. I assume that `stepCheck` in your example is the checkbox plus "STEP 1:". `aligny top` will align the topmost end of the element. I guess the checkbox has some additional border around it, so that the visible part of it is not at the very top. you can add an empty border around the `stepTitle` element to achieve the same.

Comment: Like you said checkbox elements are larger than the JLabel element. To fix this I added a 5 pixel gap above the JLabel element.  Thanks so much!